# Freeing memory of container members

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, delete-operator

I'm trying to clear up my understanding of some memory issues in C++, primarily with containers containing pointers. Say I have something like this:

Header.H

```
#ifndef test_Header_h
#define test_Header_h

#include <vector>

using std::vector;

class ClassA {
    int* intPtr;

public:
    ClassA(int n);
    ~ClassA();
};

class ClassB {
    vector<ClassA*> vecPtr;

public:
    ClassB();
    ~ClassB();

    void someFunc();
};

#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Header.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    ClassA objA(5);
    ClassB objB;

    return 0;
}

ClassA::ClassA(int n) {
    intPtr = new int[n];
}
ClassA::~ClassA() {
    delete intPtr;
}

ClassB::ClassB() {
    vecPtr = vector<ClassA*>(0);
}

ClassB::~ClassB() {
    //no destructor needed
}

void ClassB::someFunc() {
    //vecPtr = something using new;
    int* testPtr = new int[vecPtr.size()];
    //do stuff
    delete testPtr;
}
```

Does `vecPtr` ever need to be deleted? Or does the destructor of `ClassA` accomplish this for me? Also, if instead of having a `vector`, would it be the same situation if I had used a `list` of pointers or a `pair`? Finally, for clarification `testPtr` needs to be deleted in `someFunc` because that is the scope it was declared in, so putting it in the destructor would be pointless. If `testPtr` shared the address the address of an important member, deleting it would also the important member? I know there is quite a few questions but I think I'm just going around in a circular argument in my head, confusing myself more and more.

Comment: You've allocated intPtr with `new int[n];` so you should deallocate it with delete[]. See [the documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20delete[]/).

Comment: Guessing about usecase: you most likely have to explicitly `delete` every `vecPtr` element, and to provide copy constructor/assignment that will copy contents of pointers for use in destination vector.

Comment: You must `delete` anything you created with `new`.

Comment: Consider using `std::shared_ptr` / `std::unique_ptr` instead of raw-pointers

Comment: `vecPtr` is not a pointer. Seems like a bad name, based on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vecPtr` does not need to be deleted, because it is not a pointer. This might be different for the pointers in `vecPtr` and depends on who has the ownership for those pointers.

Yes, `testPtr` must be deleted, where it is available. Anything else won't even compile. If you point `testPtr` to a member and delete that, you will likely see a double free or corruption error when the member would be deleted on the destructor.

In general where something must be deleted is up to the implementation. The only thing that you need to look out for is that every new gets exactly one delete from somewhere in any code path. Usually constructors/destructor are therefore a good place.

Answer (score 0):

You have big problems here. Remember this:

1) any `new` must be balanced with a `delete`.

2) any `new[]` must be balanced with a `delete[]`.

In fact, if you mix them (as you've done), you have *undefined behaviour*. **Boom!** You need to write `delete[] intPtr;` and `delete[] testPtr;`

Also and simply put, you don't write `delete vecPtr` since you didn't write `new vecPtr`.

Internally, the C++ runtime remembers the number of elements that you've allocated using `new[]`. You need to use `delete[]` to allow that runtime to access that information.